Ubuntu 22.04 SPDIF digital out not working with Pulseaudio
Recently I got myself a new PC but since it's a SFF there's little room to install cards.
I finally found a PCIe sound card (24 bit, 192khz) with both analog and digital outputs.
I want to route the sound via the SPDIF (coaxial) to my USB DAC- DIGITAL IN (because I have another PC using the DAC as well) but somehow, there's no sound.
I googled the adjustments needed in order to use the SPDIF port and while everything seems to be OK visually (I even see the signal coming in PulseEffects) I still can't get the sound to work. The weird thing is that using Audacious player, it works flawlessly (using both 'ALSA' as 'Pulseaudio server') but pavucontrol, system sounds and most importantly for me, firefox/chrome remain totally silent.
I tried the following:
pavucontrol, made sure correct digital port is selected
alsamixer, made sure spdif isn't muted (auto mute disabled as well)
made my user account a member of the 'audio' group
created some entries in the deamon.conf file under etc/pulse
made sure files in etc/pulse are the same as in home/.config/pulse
made sure spdif port of my sound card, the RCA cable and the input of my USB DAC is working.
So it looks like some configuration problem
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on a Lenovo Thinkcentre M710s - I7-7700 SFF desktop
Sound card is a Oxygen CM8888 PCIe card.
Here are some results:
sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: CMedia [HDA C-Media], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: CMedia [HDA C-Media], device 1: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

--
pactl list short modules
0     module-device-restore
         
1     module-stream-restore 
2     module-card-restore       
3     module-augment-properties           
4     module-switch-on-port-available 
5     module-switch-on-connect            
6     module-udev-detect            
7     module-alsa-card  device_id="0" name="pci-0000_03_00.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1" 
8     module-bluetooth-policy       
9     module-bluetooth-discover           
10    module-bluez5-discover        
11    module-native-protocol-unix         
12    module-default-device-restore       
13    module-always-sink            
14    module-intended-roles         
15    module-suspend-on-idle        
16    module-systemd-login          
17    module-position-event-sounds        
18    module-role-cork        
19    module-snap-policy            
20    module-filter-heuristics            
21    module-filter-apply           
22    module-alsa-sink  device=hw:0,1 sink_name=spdif_out   
23    module-null-sink  sink_name=PulseEffects_apps sink_properties=device.description="PulseEffects(apps)"device.class="sound" norewinds=1     
24    module-null-sink  sink_name=PulseEffects_mic sink_properties=device.description="PulseEffects(mic)"device.class="sound" norewinds=1 
25    module-x11-publish      display=:1 xauthority=/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.NGO9Q2  
26    module-x11-cork-request display=:1 xauthority=/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.NGO9Q2  
27    module-x11-xsmp   display=:1 xauthority=/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.NGO9Q2 session_manager=local/mediapc-ThinkCentre-M710s:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1495,unix/mediapc-ThinkCentre-M710s:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1495  


journalctl --user-unit=pulseaudio

jul 23 18:42:31 mediapc-ThinkCentre-M710s systemd[1344]: Starting Sound Service...

jul 23 18:42:32 mediapc-ThinkCentre-M710s pulseaudio[1353]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-sink" (argument: "device=hw:0,1 sink_name=spdif_out"): initialization failed.

jul 23 18:42:32 mediapc-ThinkCentre-M710s systemd[1344]: Started Sound Service.

jul 23 18:42:32 mediapc-ThinkCentre-M710s pulseaudio[1353]: [1]GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.

I've added a screenshot of my sound settings in Ubuntu. 
Couldn't upload the daemon.conf so I paste it here:
Any help much appreciated!
daemon.conf
; daemonize = no

; fail = yes

; allow-module-loading = yes

; allow-exit = yes

; use-pid-file = yes

; system-instance = no

; local-server-type = user

; enable-shm = yes

; enable-memfd = yes

; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB

; lock-memory = no

; cpu-limit = no


high-priority = yes

nice-level = -15


; realtime-scheduling = yes

; realtime-priority = 5


; exit-idle-time = 20

; scache-idle-time = 20


; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)


; load-default-script-file = yes

; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa


; log-target = auto

; log-level = notice

; log-meta = no

; log-time = no

; log-backtrace = 0


resample-method = soxr-vhq

avoid-resampling = true

; enable-remixing = yes

; remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes

; remixing-produce-lfe = no

; remixing-consume-lfe = no

; lfe-crossover-freq = 0


; flat-volumes = no


; rescue-streams = yes


; rlimit-fsize = -1

; rlimit-data = -1

; rlimit-stack = -1

; rlimit-core = -1

; rlimit-as = -1

; rlimit-rss = -1

; rlimit-nproc = -1

; rlimit-nofile = 256

; rlimit-memlock = -1

; rlimit-locks = -1

; rlimit-sigpending = -1

; rlimit-msgqueue = -1

; rlimit-nice = 31

; rlimit-rtprio = 9

; rlimit-rttime = 200000


default-sample-format = s24le

default-sample-rate = 44100

alternate-sample-rate = 48000

; default-sample-channels = 2

; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right


; default-fragments = 4

; default-fragment-size-msec = 25


; enable-deferred-volume = yes

deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1

; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0


See my Answer on how to install pipewire which probably will solve your problem

Thanks, however, I use Ubuntu as a professional audio player in high quality and after extensive listening experience I must say that the sound quality of Pipewire, as it is now, isn't 100% on par with the sound quality on Pulse audio. It seems to be more |clinical" and lifeless sounding to me and that is a problem so that's why I chose to install ubuntu 22.04 (with default pulse audio sound engine) instead of 24.04 (pipewire default)
There are errors in the log so I just want to know what's wrong.

Also, I'd like to use PulseEffects since a particular effect has a better sound quality which was with the introduction of Easyeffects replaced by another library.

I've worked about 30 years in the sound business (creating PAs for EV and studio equipement) and had a similar experience with the first CDs. I'm still convinced that analog (with its 3rd harmonics) will beat any digital system. This is the first time I heard a digital system beats another one. Basically it is the sample rate (44,1khz) an bit depth that'll make the difference. You might check the default settings of pipewire, but physically they shouldn't be different.  Since both (pulseaudio and pipewire) run on the same hardware the key is configuration...
